# Variable list of generic arguments?

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to declare a signature for a variable amount of generic arguments in C#?

For example, I'd like to turn this concrete method:

```
private IEnumerable<Agent> DefaultJoinedQuery(string query, object param = null)
{
     return _connection.Query<Agent, Broker, Agent>(query, (a, b) => { a.Broker = b; return a; }, param);
}
```

Into this:

```
private IEnumerable<TEntity> DefaultJoinedQuery(string query, Func<..., TEntity> joinFunc, object param = null)
{
     return _connection.Query<..., TEntity>(query, joinFunc(...), param);
}
```

So is C# dynamic enough to allow me to write one method for an arbitraty amount of generic arguments?

Comment: No, it isn't. You can define a series of overloads with increasing number of generic parameters, or you can dynamically invoke the delegate with reflection but there's no built-in syntax for this.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Okay, that's what I feared. Hopefully they'll implement it in C# 7.0 :)

Comment: I wouldn't count on it, all the C# 7 information is live on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). You haven't really explained how you expected this to work either, how would you pass in arguments to the function inside that method, for instance?

Comment: In the first example where does `Broker` come from? I dont see any variable number of generic arguments, I see three!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Could this be a a feature that is not requested by the community?

Comment: @Jamiec That's a concrete implementation that should match the signature below...

Comment: Could be, but again, the important part for implementation is not that people ask for it, it is that there is a good case for it and it is possible, and I don't mean that in the "we just have to write the code to implement it" possible, but in terms of "what does this even mean?" possible. It also has to win over other competing things to be implemented in order to be prioritized and [every new thing starts with minus 100 points](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/).

Comment: So you would have to justify *why* and it would have to solve a *general* problem. If you posted a request on github for a feature like this, with the same amount of details as in this question you would only get back "What do you mean?" questions.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So people wouldn't see any sense in adding this feature? It'd definitely save a lot of space so that you wouldn't have to define the signature like 10 times to cover most developers' needs.

Comment: @silkfire this is a feature that is *not needed* by any of the strongly-typed languages. A `<T1,T2,T3>` is the same as a `< <T1,T2>, T3>`. You can specify an infinite number of types this way. That's how both the functional languages and C++ deal with multiple types. Besides, a long list of types is a significant design smell

Comment: You're asking for a strongly typed *dynamic* solution. Ponder the question a bit.

Comment: Wait [variadic templates in C++ !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Not sure I understand? Aren't generics just that?